# C# - xNet Proxy support

Tags: c#, xnet

I wanted to ask if it's possible to use xNet with Proxies?

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
      var attempt = request.Post("https://api.zcdn.de/oauth/authorizations").ToString();
}
```

the problem is that I have to use proxies to change my IP to avoid Bans... how can I do it with xNet library?
and how can I use socks 4 or socks 5 as proxies?

Answer (score 0):

sure you can do it with proxy.

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    string proxy = "127.0.0.1:8888";

    request["Accept"] = "*/*";
    request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse(proxy);

    var attempt = request.Post("https://api.zcdn.de/oauth/authorizations").ToString();
}
```